# How to concretely find the characters and pure states of $L^\infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $(X, \mathcal X, \mu)$ be a space with measure. Out of curiosity I was trying to understand what the Gelfand-Naimark theorem and [Glimm's abstract Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970133) give when applied to the $\Bbb C$ $*$-algebra $L^\infty(X,\mu)$. Sadly, I had to give up: given that its elements are not functions with pointwise values, how can I find the pure states and characters of $L^\infty$ (i.e see how they look like concretely)?

Comment: This is not a full answer. It is not a trivial calculation in most cases. But, for example, it is easy to show that the set of characters on $l^\infty (\Bbb{N})$ is isomorphic to $\beta \Bbb{N}$. Another example: it can be shown that $L^\infty([0,1])\cong C(Y)$ where $Y$ is extremely disconnected.
In general, for abelian von-Neumann algebra, $L^\infty(X,\mu)$, which is isomorphic (by the Gelfand isomorphism) to $C(Y)$, $Y$ must be extremely disconnected. So, the set of characters (evaluations) is isomorphic to $Y$. 
In the abelian case, characters=pure states.

Comment: @ShirlyGeffen: Are extremely disconnected spaces the same thing as [extremally disconnected spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremally_disconnected_space)? Also, how is $X$ related to $Y$?

Comment: Yes, I meant extremally disconnected. For the second question, I don't know.

Comment: In general, $L^\infty(X, \mu)$ is not a von Neumann algebra!

Answer (score 2):

Expanding barely on what Shirly said, you cannot expect any explicit image of the characters (and even less the pure states, then). As a C$^*$-algebra, one sees $L^\infty(X)$ as $C(\tilde X)$, where $\tilde X$ is nothing but the space of characters. This is never explicit unless $X$ is finite; even in the infinite discrete case, as Shirly mentioned, $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ is $C(\beta\mathbb N)$, and describing the Stone-Cech compactification is equivalent to describing all free ultrafilters on $\mathbb N$ (which is impossible to do explicitly).

Finally, note that  using non-separable C$^*$-algebras as a source for intuition is not a very good idea. There is enough variety and crazyness with separable C$^*$-algebras, that it is better to leave the non-separable ones at rest.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant description is given [here](https://eprints.lancs.ac.uk/id/eprint/55803/1/DissertatmeasurealgebraSUBMITTEDCHANGES.pdf) (Proposition 2.15).

It boils down to the observation that the sought Gelfand space is the Stone space of the Boolean algebra of measurable sets modulo the null sets.