# What is the cardinality of $K$, where $L_\infty[0,1]=C(K)$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, gelfand-representation

By Gelfand representation of (real) C$^*$-algebras, it is known that $L_\infty[0,1]$ is isometrically isomorphic to $C(K)$, for some compact Hausdorff $K$. By looking at the proof, $K$ is actually defined in the following way:
$$K=\{\mu\in L_\infty^*:\|\mu\|=\mu(e)=1\text{ and }\mu(fg)=\mu(f)\mu(g)\text{ for all }f,g\in L_\infty\},$$
where $e$ is the unit of the C$^*$-algebra (that is, in this case the 1-constant function). Moreover, it is proved that $K$ is non-empty since it contains the extreme points of the set $\{\mu\in L_\infty^*:\|\mu\|=\mu(e)=1\}$. Can we say anything about the cardinality of this set $K$?

So far I've been able to show the following topological lemma:

$\textbf{Lemma:}$ A compact Hausdorff countable space is metrizable.

Since $C(K)=L_\infty$ is non-separable, it is known that this implies that $K$ must be non-metrizable. This, combined with the lemma, shows that $K$ is uncountable. Can we do better than this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the subject,  however the Lemma appears to only show one direction (if compact countable  Hausdorff, then non-metrizable),  thus just being non-metrizable wouldn't mean it is uncountable?

Comment: @Alan, $K$ is non-metrizable, but also compact and Hausdorff.

Comment: My point was the Lemma doesn't seem to be an "if and only if"

Comment: I assume it is not, but this is only a contradiction argument to show it cannot be countable.

Comment: Some relevant discussion: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2180913/144766

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space $K$ you are interested in arises as the Stone space of the Boolean algebra of measurable subsets of the interval modulo the null sets, which is complete. All you have to do is to count the ultrafilters and for this, you can use the [Balcar-Franek theorem](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/%7Efranek/bf.html) to conclude there are precisely $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ of them. Consequently,

$$|K| = 2^{\mathfrak{c}},$$

where $\mathfrak{c}$ is the cardinality of the contiuum.

A more general result may be found [here](https://eprints.lancs.ac.uk/id/eprint/55803/1/DissertatmeasurealgebraSUBMITTEDCHANGES.pdf) (Proposition 2.15).

Comment: What is $\mathfrak c$?